# One of my MySQL database tables empties every night, how do I make it stop?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

For the last two nights I've lost all of the data in just one of my tables. I don't have any cron jobs setup. I checked crontab -e for both root and my primary user on my ec2 server and they are empty. Please help.

Also, in past experience emptying a table causes the id's of newly inserted rows to start over at 0. The id's of rows that i'm inserting into the emptied table now are continuing from where the old data left off, perhaps suggesting that the old data is still there?

P.S.
There are no triggers s, but when I go to the SQL query section of phpmyadmin I found the following line of code: SELECT * FROM articles WHERE 1; It had "do not overwrite this query from outside this window" selected as well as "show this query here again". It just so happens that my articles table is what was being deleted. Could this be the source of my problem?

Comment: Neither you have set a recurring task in your phpmyadmin, or you have been "hacked".

Comment: where in phpmyadmin do I access the recurring tasks. Also, I should add that as I insert new data to repopulate the database the row id's keep going up from where the old (disappeared) ones left off.

Comment: `DELETE * FROM myTable` won't reset auto_increment. Neither will `EMPTY myTable`; `TRUNCATE myTable` will.

Comment: No triggers, but when I go to the SQL query section of phpmyadmin I found the following line of code: SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE 1; It had "do not overwrite this query from outside this window" selected as well as "show this query here again". It just so happens that my articles table is what was being deleted. Could this be the source of my problem?

Comment: To see recurring tasks in phpMyAdmin, click on a schema name, then click the tab past "Routines" which is "Events." It may be hiding under the "More" tab. Events are routines that run automatically on a schedule.

Comment: You may also have a routine or a query running outside phpMyAdmin, from an operating system schedule like `cron`.

Comment: "There are no routines to display" and "There are no events to display" and Event scheduler status is OFF. HOWEVER, the size of my mysteriously emptying table is oddly large. At 208 KiB its far larger than any other table, yet seems to have far less content. Could my missing rows be hidden?

Comment: ok i see that innoDB doesn'y release disk space upon being emptied...that explains the size.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the SELECT code which was stored in the query box, the table emptying ceased to occur.

Comment: Hi Martin, please add additional details to your question by editing it. Also, that query has absolutely no impact on your server. It's stored by phpMyAdmin and isn't even loaded if you're not browsin the phpMyAdmin site. If your problem has been resolved, it wasn't because of this